# Adding up fields in Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

So I'm editing a old Jasper document we have in our system. The document presents a packing slip based on a XML file.

Now we would like to do the following:

If there is more than 1 article line with the same article we would like to add those up / combine them into one line.

I'm not very familiar with iReport and I only made some small field linking changes.

When I look at the Xml of the document I see that you can use expressions on textfields that hold some code. I think I would need to write some code for the group representing the article lines right?

Below is the xml part of the article line:

```
<detail>
        <band height="38" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-19_1" style="column_field_small" x="228" y="2" width="264" height="12" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{articleDescription}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-20_2" style="column_field_small" x="5" y="2" width="222" height="12" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{articleCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="staticText-31_5" style="sub_column_header_small" x="229" y="14" width="39" height="12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$R{CWjp.Quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="staticText-32_6" style="sub_column_header_small" x="272" y="14" width="24" height="12"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$R{CWjp.Pack}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="staticText-33_7" style="sub_column_header_small" x="415" y="14" width="52" height="12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$R{CWjp.Grossweight}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="staticText-34_8" style="sub_column_header_small" x="469" y="14" width="61" height="12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$R{CWjp.Nettweight}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-21_3" style="sub_column_field_small" x="490" y="26" width="40" height="12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{finalNetWeight}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-22_4" style="sub_column_field_small" x="427" y="26" width="40" height="12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{finalGrossWeight}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-23_5" style="sub_column_field_small" x="272" y="26" width="24" height="12"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{finalPackageCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="###0" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-24_6" style="sub_column_field_small" x="228" y="26" width="40" height="12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{finalQuantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-23_5" style="sub_column_field_small" x="300" y="26" width="80" height="12"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[( $F{serialCode} != null && $F{serialCode}.length() > 0 ? $F{serialCode} :
( $F{customersPalletCode} != null && $F{customersPalletCode}.length() > 0 ? $F{customersPalletCode} :
( $F{lotCode} != null && $F{lotCode}.length() > 0 ? $F{lotCode} : "" )) )]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="staticText-32_6" style="sub_column_header_small" x="300" y="14" width="80" height="12">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(1==2)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$R{CWjp.SerPltLotCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="staticText-32_6" style="sub_column_header_small" x="380" y="26" width="43" height="12"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["(" + ( $F{serialCode} != null && $F{serialCode}.length() > 0 ? $R{CWjp.Serial} :
( $F{customersPalletCode} != null && $F{customersPalletCode}.length() > 0 ? $R{CWjp.Pallet} :
( $F{lotCode} != null && $F{lotCode}.length() > 0 ? $R{CWjp.Lot1} : "" )) )
+ ")"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [Groups](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/groups). Keep in mind that the data must be sorted before grouping should be applied.

Comment: I have read through the article on grouping. As far as I understand this puts the "article-lines" in a group so that I could make an expression sorting them out or how does this work? The document does not really explain how to work with them only implementing them. Some sample would help me a lot in understanding this. Unfortunatly i cant find much on google ect.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5RlXDFsoD4pTGpzRkxTR3FCV0U/view?usp=sharing) is a sample report that utilizes iReports sample database so you can test drive it, The report groups data by shipcountry (notice that shipcountry comes first in the order by clause).